# How fix chrome extension notifications error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If i try to call `chrome.notifications.create` in background.js file in extension console i get error

```
Error handling response: ReferenceError: Image is not defined
    at loadImageData (extensions::imageUtil:11:13)
    at Object.loadAllImages (extensions::imageUtil:74:5)
    at replaceNotificationOptionURLs (extensions::notifications:89:13)
    at extensions::notifications:115:5
    at chrome-extension://ajjociodcpfbemlakfiokkijffnppmkn/background.js:59:32
```

Image for notification is located in the root folder

```
const options = {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'icon.png',
        title: 'Background.js',
        message: 'Hello from background.js!',
      };
      chrome.notifications.create(options);
```

but if you make the same call in the popup file, everything works correctly

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://crbug.com/1168477) in ManifestV3 fixed in Chrome 91. Until then use a manually constructed data URI which you can generate from your png online.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I tried convert [here](https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-data-uri), but the error remains the same

Comment: I guess ManifestV2 is the only option until then.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried iconUrl: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA but still it doesnt work. Is that the workaround syntax good?

Comment: Use ManifestV2.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? @Filya